# Ho to strip and replace values in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have around 200,000 records of data with phone numbers, but the numbers are inconsistent.

for example, some may be 10 digits (missing a 0 at the beginning), some have spaces in there, some have a '-' in the middle and some begin with '+44' instead of 0.

Is there a way in mySQL to condition all these and cleanse the data in one query?

Comment: post sample data of each scenario and also what you want your cleansed output to be.

Comment: And define cleanse.

Comment: As first step, you can use MySQL's `REPLACE()` function to get rid of unwanted chars (spaces, `-` etc), other cases probably require regular expressions. Try to do something on your own and then ask specific question if result won't be satisfying. Also it may be easier to do that outside of MySQL, e.g. in PHP, Python or any other programming language.

Comment: I need to strip all white spaces then the types of conditions are "1234567891" - in this case if the number has 10 numbers add a 0 to the beginning. also "+441234567891" if it has "+44" at the beginning it should replace "+44" for "0" and lastly if any number has a "-" in there it should remove the "-" along with the white spaces. (the field is a string). thanks for your help ive been trying to do it for hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without sample data and without an example output this is purely speculative and assuming you want the output in the format of `01234567891`.

Use a combination of `LENGTH`, `REPLACE' AND`LEFT` functions to resolve the 4 issues you highlighted:

1. Missing 0 at beggining.
2. Spaces in the string.
3. -'s in the string.
4. +44 rather than 0.

---

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LENGTH(REPLACE(REPLACE(numberfield, '-', ''), ' ', '')) = 10 
                THEN CONCAT('0', REPLACE(REPLACE(numberfield, '-', ''), ' ', ''))
                WHEN LEFT(REPLACE(REPLACE(numberfield, '-', ''), ' ', ''), 3) = '+44'
                THEN REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(numberfield, '-', ''), ' ', ''), '+44', '0'
           END AS Cleannumber
    FROM yourtable
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the phone number field is a string - the following should deal with the conditions you specified :

```
RIGHT( LPAD( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE('phonenumber', '-', ''), '+44', ''), ' ', ''), 11, '0' ), 11 )
```

first any '-' are removed, then '+44' is removed, then spaces are removed, then 11 '0's are added to the start of the number, finally the rightmost 11 characters are taken.

So you would do an UPDATE query replacing the phonenumber column.

Comment: Why are 10 0's added?

Comment: @pandemic - edited to 11, but it is just to ensure that the final number returned is 11 characters long. If you know at most 1 zero will be missing - you could just add 1.